# Confirm in Kendo UI Treeview Drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to impliment drag drop with confirmation in a Kendo UI Treeview. I'm linking to the latest version of the kendo controls via their CDN.

My treeview is created using the following code (data source ommited for brevity):

```
$("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
    dragAndDrop: true,
    dataSource: {....}
    drop: onDrop,
});

function onDrop(e) {
    var nodeText = this.text(e.sourceNode);
    e.setValid(confirm("Sure you want to drop: " + nodeText));
}
```

If I run the code using the latest version of chrome then all is well, however using IE or Firefox a second confirm dialog is displayed when you mouse over the first dialog.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KpEej/1/

How can I fix this so only one confirm is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug related to kendo events and alert.

You can find details [here.](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/drag-and-drop/kendodroptarget-drop-fires-event-twice.aspx)

You should lose the confirm dialog and use a jQuery dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've reported the problem to Telerik and they have confirmed the bug. They also expect it to be fixed in an internal release later this week (07 Jan 2014)